# Execute 2 dataframes inside a function in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have been working on a script where 2 dataframes are being used within a function. df1 and df2.

Till now i have used an function for a single dataframe but i dont understand how to work around 2 dataframes.

When working separately (without using any function) it works well but i am not getting how to use the function where we have to deal with 2 dataframes. **df1 and df2**

**Dataframe1**

```
id_number  company_name        match_acc

IN2231D    AXN pvt Ltd
UK654IN    Aviva Intl Ltd
SL1432H    Ship Incorporations
LK0678G    Oppo Mobiles pvt ltd
NG5678J    Nokia Inc
```

**Dataframe2**

```
identity_no   Pincode   company_name

 IN2231        110030    AXN pvt Ltd
 UK654IN       897653    Aviva Intl Ltd
 SL1432        07658     Ship Incorporations
 LK0678G       120988    Oppo Mobiles Pvt Ltd
```

**Getting the Output:**

```
id_number          company_name  match_acc
  IN2231D           AXN pvt Ltd         92
  UK654IN        Aviva Intl Ltd        100
  SL1432H   Ship Incorporations         92
  LK0678G  Oppo Mobiles pvt ltd        100
  NG5678J             Nokia Inc         43
```

**Code i have been using:**

```
df1 = pd.read_excel(open(r'input.xlsx', 'rb'), sheet_name='sheet1')
df2 = pd.read_excel(open(r'input.xlsx', 'rb'), sheet_name='sheet2')
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz
```

> Looking to use the below script inside a function For Eg. def test(x):

```
cross = df1[['id_number']].merge(df2[['identity_no']], how='cross')
cross = cross.dropna(subset=['GST_No','GSTIN'])
cross['match'] = cross.apply(lambda x: fuzz.ratio(x.id_number, x.identity_no), axis=1)
df1['match_acc'] = df1.id_number.map(cross.groupby('id_number').match.max())
```

The above script works fine but i don't understand how can i use the script inside an function and later on use it on a dataframe.

Need Suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I don't get what you want, but why not handing over two dataframes to the function?

```py
import pandas as pd
def test(df1: pd.DataFrame, df2: pd.DataFrame):
    cross = df1[['id_number']].merge(df2[['identity_no']], how='cross')
    cross = cross.dropna(subset=['GST_No','GSTIN'])
    cross['match'] = cross.apply(lambda x: fuzz.ratio(x.id_number, x.identity_no), axis=1)
    df1['match_acc'] = df1.id_number.map(cross.groupby('id_number').match.max())
```